# Only getting documents matching specific query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have multiple documents with the same subject_id and am using an aggregate  project and match query to only get those that match a certain criteria. But because there are multiple documents with the same subject_id, I am getting those that have at least that one criteria.

```
db.subs.aggregate([ { '$group': 
               { _id: '$subject_id', test_04: { '$push':'$metrics.test_04' } }},
               { '$match': { test_04: '3- 5 or more' } } ])
```

I am receiving the following:

```
{ _id: 'sub1', test_04: [ '3- 5 or more' ] },
{ _id: 'sub2', test_04: [ '3- 5 or more', '3- 5 or more' ] },
{ _id: 'sub7', test_04: [ '2- 3 or 4', '3- 5 or more' ] },
{ _id: 'sub13', test_04: [ '3- 5 or more' ] },
{ _id: 'sub19', test_04: [ '3- 5 or more' ] }
```

but I only want

```
{ _id: 'sub1', test_04: [ '3- 5 or more' ] },
{ _id: 'sub13', test_04: [ '3- 5 or more' ] },
{ _id: 'sub19', test_04: [ '3- 5 or more' ] }
```

Comment: `'3- 5 or more'` this is length of the array?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet no, this is just the value of the variable "test_04"

Comment: Why not sub2 and sub7 ? What is the criteria for being grouped?

Comment: I just want the documents that have '3- 5 or more' in the test_04 field.

Comment: Something like this https://mongoplayground.net/p/xIBPA6TVmYw ?????